# PhD project that I cannot do on my own - what happens then?

Tags: phd, thesis, application, portugal

I am considering applying for a PhD in Design and my idea for a Phd project is creating an innovative app. What concerns me is that I do not know how to develop apps, I am not a developer but a UX/UI designer.

So my role would be to research, build the structure and architecture of the app, design the features, the visual appearance, etc., but I do need it developed for the purposes of the research and user testing (to see if my seemingly innovative idea even works) and that's not something I can do on my own.

What should I do in this situation? Is it a bad idea for a project since I cannot do it on my own?  Or do I just go and hire a developer to help me with creating it? Do I then fund it from my own pocket or is it something that the university can potentially help me with?

Thank you!

Comment: If you register for the site interactions will be easier. But what country is this? Edit or add a country tag, please. You might look at the following for ideas on graduate admissions various places: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368

Comment: ow sorry, first time posting here. I'd be applying to the University of Lisbon, so that's Portugal (I am Ukrainian but I live in PT).

Comment: Can you get a PhD for writing an app? If it's about some feature of the UI then maybe you don't need a working app but a test bench of some kind. A university department that does this sort of thing will be able to guide you as to what is available. For example, a test bench that records things like where a user clicks, what they type then erase, etc.

Comment: @Dan, getting a doctorate for an app would be very unlikely, but needing an app to do some research is common enough.

Comment: You should read some PhD theses in your area of study to get a good idea of what is expected.  They should say what help was received.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a PhD program requires you to do some novel and substantive *research* that will advance scholarly knowledge.  Often there is an expectation that this will manifest in publication of work in scholarly journals, but in design programs they may allow your main output to be a novel object or system.  Even in this latter case, your output from the program should contribute something novel and substantive in the discipline.  Producing an app could potentially meet this requirement if it is sufficiently innovative from a design perspective, but you should seek advice on this from some academics in your field.

In principle, there is no bar to you having your app programmed by someone else, so long as your own contribution (in terms of design, etc.) is sufficient to meet the requirements of a PhD --- i.e., some aspect of your proposed design *advances knowledge* in your field of design.  Everyone doing a PhD uses resources and facilities created by others --- e.g., I did not design the word processor I used to write my dissertation or the printer I used to print it.  Your PhD proposal should set out clearly what is your own role and what part you intend to give to a programmer.  Since the focus of the program is on design, it is not unreasonable that your own contribution would be in that area, and the programming work need not necessarily be part of your role in the project.  This should be clear in your proposal in order to allow the university to assess whether your work will be sufficient for a PhD program.

As to the mechanics and costs of having it programmed for you, it would be worthwhile to undertake some preliminary enquiries about the costs for this, and include this information in your PhD proposal.  PhD programs usually have some budget for students for research related costs, though there is a modest limit to this.  If the cost of programming is above what the Department will fund then you could seek alternative sources of money/labour.  It might be worth seeing if there are researchers in computer science who would provide programming work in exchange for partial authorship credit on the app, co-authorship of publications relating to the app, etc.  Alternatively, you could seek outside funding (e.g., from investors), or you could self-fund the difference.  If your app can be monetised then you might be willing to find investors willing to contribute money or programming work in exchange for partial ownership.  You will need to check that this is compatible with the university policy on ownership of products coming out of PhD programs to ensure all proposed ownership stakes are non-contradictory.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how graduate admissions work in Portugal, but you would probably need an advisor's permission for the following, which I think might be feasible.

The professors at the university teach undergraduates in CS and they often give large projects to their students (US experience). If that is the same, then, with your advisor's permission, you might approach the instructor of some programming projects course and give them your ideas for an app as a possible project. You would probably have to stay involved, of course. But that seems natural for a UI/UX designer.

Alternatively, if there is grant money available through the university or the professor, a programmer might be hired for this task.

But, independent of any app, your research idea has to be interesting to an advisor. If you need to work with a potential advisor as part of the application process then you might bring up this need then.